# How to have a single view controller for changing multiple UIImageView and UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, view

I am creating a cooking app that contains multiple different recipes. Since 
I will need to create a view controller for each recipe/meal, it would be duplicating a lot of views, such as imageview, textview, etc. Can I have one view interexchanging the recipes? And how would I call on a specific recipe and it's image, ingredients, title, etc.?
Btw I am new to Swift, so if someone can please explain how to do this?

**Update:**

**This is what I have so far. How do I return one specific recipe to the `BasicBreakfastViewController`?**

```
class Recipes: NSObject {
    var recipeName = ""
    //name of recipe 
    var prepTime = ""
    //preparation time 
    var imageFile = ""
    //image filename of recipe
    var ingredients: [Any] = []
    // ingredients
    var step1 = ""
    var step2 = ""
    //recipe directions
    var calories: Int = 0  
}
```

```
//BreakfastRecipesViewController
class BreakfastRecipesViewController: UIViewController{
    var recipe: Recipes?

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var prepTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var caloriesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var directionStep1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var directionStep2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ingredientsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addToListBtn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func handleSwipe(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let riceCakeRecipe = Recipes()
        riceCakeRecipe.recipeName = "PEANUT BUTTER AND BANANA RICE CAKE"
        riceCakeRecipe.prepTime = "5 Minutes"
        riceCakeRecipe.imageFile = "IMG_273711.JPG"
        //riceCakeRecipe.calories = 281
        riceCakeRecipe.ingredients = ["• 2 Rice Cakes", "• 2 Tbsp Peanut Butter", "• 1/2 Banana"]
        riceCakeRecipe.step1 = "Distribute peanut butter evenly onto the rice cakes."
        riceCakeRecipe.step2 = "Chop half of a banana and place on top of peanut butter."

        let proteinBarkRecipe = Recipes()
        proteinBarkRecipe.recipeName = "FROZEN YOGURT PROTEIN BARK"
        proteinBarkRecipe.prepTime = "15 Minutes"
        proteinBarkRecipe.imageFile = "IMG_298611.JPG"
        //riceCakeRecipe.calories = 364
        proteinBarkRecipe.ingredients = ["• 1 Cup Greek Yogurt", "• 32g Vanilla Protein Powder", "• 5 Large Fresh Strawberries", "• 1 Tbsp Dark Chocolate", "• 1 Tsp Coconut Flakes"]
        proteinBarkRecipe.step1 = "Mix the yogurt and protein powder together until well combined."
        proteinBarkRecipe.step2 = "Line a baking sheet with foil and spread a thick layer of the yogurt mixture on top."

       var recipes = [riceCakeRecipe, proteinBarkRecipe]



        recipeTitle.text = recipe?.recipeName
        prepTimeLabel.text = recipe?.prepTime
        recipeImage.image = UIImage(named: recipe!.imageFile)
        directionStep1.text = recipe?.step1
        directionStep2.text = recipe?.step2
        //caloriesLabel.text = recipe?.calories

        return

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }


}
```

Comment: You should start by defining the structure of your data.  You can then design a single view that can be used to represent a visual representation of this data (this is what MVC is all about)

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please take a look at my update and see if this is okay to do. Also, how would I be able to call on / return one of the two recipes?

Comment: first create a tableViewController containing list of recipe tapping on a recipe call should open viewController that will show the details of recipe, pass data to this controller when tapping on a cell of tableViewController

Comment: @AbuUlHassan what if I am using UIImageView's with tap gestures in the previous view controller? In this view controller I would like the image to change when I call one of them programmatically, and then when, for instance, I call on rice cake image and it is tapped, then the next view controller will display the rice cake image, the name of the recipe, ingredients needed, etc. If the image in the previous view controller displays the other recipe, and when I tap on the image then that recipes info will be shown in the next view controller.

Comment: you should add all of your recipes in an array of recipe. and set tags of imageView according to index of recipe and then get the tag of imageView when tapped and using that tag get the recipe from array of recipe.